# File operations are not working on atom

Tags: python, c++, atom-editor

I started learning python yesterday and I am more comfortable to use files for input and output. So, I wrote the following code and ran it from atom text editor. But I got the following error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'**.

```
import sys

def init():
    orig_stdin = sys.stdin
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    fin = file('input.txt', 'r')
    fout = file('output.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdin = fin
    sys.stdout = fout
    return

init()

x = raw_input()
print(x)
```

To check if if the problem was only with python I wrote the following C++ code. But again I had no output (no error message this time).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
const int N = 1000005;

int x;

void init(){
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
}

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

Both of this codes works fine on **sublime text** editor.

> The issue is fixed. I was a bit silly. The problem was with the working directory.

Comment: I don't use Atom but it seems that it comes with a "working directory" feature. Are you sure that the working directory is the same as the one which contains `input.txt`? See https://discuss.atom.io/t/newbie-question-changing-working-directory/11635/4

Comment: Unrelated: redirecting standart io *inside a program* is at least uncommon and definitely not a good practice because you will never be able to use the standard shell redirections. It is ok if you only use it in test programs but avoid such an antipattern in real code...

Comment: @raganjosh yes, and as I mentioned it works fine on sublime text

Comment: I don't get how that's related?

Comment: To confirm the working directory problem just add `import os` `print(os.getcwd())`. Then run using sublime and atom. The cause should be evident...

Comment: @raganjosh, if it works on other editors, then i can assume i have no problem with my code ( file directory or path )

Comment: No, the _editor_ has a working directory. You can assume that this is not the case if you wish, but your problem will persist. I use Canopy and I have to set the working directory manually if I start new scripts in a different directory. This has nothing to do with the working directory of any other program I use.

Comment: @raganjosh, i worked with sublime text a lot and i worked with different directories. but i never had these problems. i don't know if there is any issue with atom.

Comment: @raganjosh, even the code works fine running from terminal (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: We're going in circles. You can either try the suggestions from myself and Serge or you can just leave this unsolved. You have _not_ set the path in your code (where in "input.txt" are you specifying the path?). The code relies on the working directory being set, and this is likely coming from the editor. Also, please spell my name correctly as I receive no notifications otherwise.

Comment: BTW, my remark on redirecting standart io is not that unrelated. At least you should use absolute paths or force the current directory of **your** process (in Python: `os.chdir("/path/to/folder")`)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, i got it now. the problem occurred as i had the root directory of current folder as project folder. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, and i was too lazy to check your suggestion because it was working in other editors.

Comment: @FerozAhmmed -- If your goal was to direct I/O from the keyboard and screen to an input/output file, the way you do it without `freopen` in C++ is to do [something like this](http://ideone.com/4VnQbY).  The stream operators in C++ are derived from `std::ostream, std::istream`, and all you have to do is point to the correct stream to input from and write to.

Comment: @roganjosh: As it solved OP's problem, you should make your suggestion an answer so that OP can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'`when trying to open a file that you are sure exists, you should first suspect that there is an issue with your current working directory.

This can easily be tested by:

```
import os
print (os.getcwd())
```

The fact that code works in one editor doesn't influence whether it will work in another editor unless the cwd is set correctly for each editor. In the case of Atom, one way to change the current working directory is `atom.project.setPath(...)` but other routes are available [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/newbie-question-changing-working-directory/11635)